# How do Facebook Login Graph versions relate to the js and php sdks and cordova plugins?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I’m upgrading Facebook login on my web-app, which is also compiled into iOS and Android versions via Cordova. It’s been a number of years since I did the original FB Login intergration. I'm wondering if you can please help me to get my head around how the php and js SDK versioning system works.

I use both the PHP and Javascript FB Login SDKs, and cordova-plugin-facebook4 for the iOS & Android versions

The php Facebook SDK I have is v4

The js SDK the web-app loads is at https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js (the version targeted in FB.init is v2.6 - does this mean it’s targeting Graph version 2.6?)

The scope I’m asking for is “email” in the web-app and [“email”,”public_profile”] in Cordova

I’m also in the process of upgrading php from 5.5.38 to 8

I’m trying to figure out how much longer my current FB login js and php SDK graph versions will work, so that if my php upgrade isn’t ready to go by the time they’re deprecated, I can see if there’s a server-side only solution (compatible with php  5.5.38) I can implement as a plan b until the php 8 upgrade is done.

From what I can tell (via https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog) Graph v4 will die on Nov 5

- does this mean my Facebook calls will die from Nov 5?
- since the js SDK for FB login is always loaded from the same URL ie it’s always the latest version, does that mean that it’s just the Cordova V4 and php SDK v4 that I need to upgrade?
- when I search for “Facebook SDK for PHP” on https://php-download.com, the highest version I can find is v5. Does this mean it’s only compatible with Graph v5, and if so, where are the higher versions of the php SDK found? I see the FB graph goes up to v11 now.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: The version of the PHP SDK has nothing to do with the Graph API version. (Not directly; if they add anything new on the API side, that requires new methods in the SDK, then you would have to upgrade to the latest version.) You _specify_ the API version you want to target via your configuration. And if you specify a lower API version that the lowest one currently available, then you calls will be silently upgraded to the latter automatically, on Facebook's end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cordova-plugin-facebook4` is deprecated. I'd recommend using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-facebook-connect. By default, that plugin is currently using v11 of the Facebook iOS and Android SDKs, and the SDK major versions match the Graph API version, so the SDKs are using v11.0. If you for some reason wish to use a different version, you can specify  `FACEBOOK_IOS_SDK_VERSION` and `FACEBOOK_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION` preferences when adding the plugin.